# how to pass returned value from JavaScript function as asp-route value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to do something like below-

```
function GetParentID() {
    var tv = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView'),
    selected = tv.select(),
    item = tv.dataItem(selected);
    var Value= (item.ID);
    return Value;
}
```

Then i want to use the returned value like this-

```
<a asp-area="Marketing" asp-controller="Store" asp-action="Create" asp-route-ID="GetParentID()"  class="btn btn-default">Create</a>
```

I have try to save the value in hidden input like this:

```
<input id="p_ID" type="hidden" />
```

then fill this input throw jQuery and it's work like this :

```
$('#p_ID').val(GetParentID());
```

but still can't pass this value as asp-route-ID how i can achieve something like that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mainly asp-route-ID="321545" Tag Helpers are server side helpers and not client side

So, you can not use client side script on server side like

JavaScript: deal only with Html and CSS (Client Side)

C# + Razor + TagHelpers: are server side (executed on the server)

So, one of the ways is to send a request using a link to the server and assign the value on the server side
OR
is to see how link is generated on the client:
/MyWeb/MyPageIndex/123545

if we can say 123545 is the asp-route-ID then you need to:
call the link and change 123545 at client
Example:

```
<a id="stest" href="/MyWeb/MyPageIndex/123545" />
$("#stest").attr("href", "/MyWeb/MyPageIndex/" + GetParentID());
```

you can read here:
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx